How do you find how much a simple concave polygon can be deflated/offset before it self intersects?
For reference, I've implemented this algorithm for inflating/deflating polygons: https://www.baeldung.com/cs/polygons-inflating-deflating
However, for joining edges, instead of using rounded corners, I am using a line-line intersection algorithm to find where each 2 adjacent edges intersect to find the new coordinates for each vertex.
The problem I am facing is that I don't know how much a polygon can be inflated or deflated before it self-intersects. This is a problem because my polygon library only works well with simple/non-self intersecting polygons (it won't produce a good looking result unless the polygon doesn't self-intersect), so I would need to clamp the factor in which the polygon is deflated.
The next problem is that the solution must work with concave polygons, which was the biggest hindrance to finding a solution.
Now, my initial thought was that I could find the shortest edge of the polygon, and half of that edge's length would be the most the polygon could be inflated, however I realized that would only work for convex polygons. For concave polygons (particularly at at the reflex vertices), the new point of intersection is further away than those at convex vertices.
For example, suppose we have the following polygon:

When we "deflate" it by, say, 0.5 units, we get the following:

As you can see, circled in blue, the vertex is about to intersect the rightmost edge, so my initial theory (of finding the shortest edge) would result in a factor of 1.5 since the shortest edge is 3 units long. Of course, a factor of 1.5 would be too large and would result in a self-intersection because of that vertex.
Now that leads me to where I am now. Is there a way (without trial and error) to find the largest factor the concave polygon can be deflated?
